# Add continuous counts from previous month

Tags: t-sql

Is there a way to add the previous months counts to the next month, for example in the table below Jan has 17 and Feb 29, I need Feb to show 46 and the March to show 46 plus the actual counts from March. I need to keep track of the progress made.

```
SELECT  ReviewType,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 1 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jan,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 2 THEN ReviewType END) AS Feb,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 3 THEN ReviewType END) AS Mar,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 4 THEN ReviewType END) AS Apr,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 5 THEN ReviewType END) AS May,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 6 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jun,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 7 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jul,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 8 THEN ReviewType END) AS Aug,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 9 THEN ReviewType END) AS Sep,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 10 THEN ReviewType END) AS Oct,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 11 THEN ReviewType END) AS Nov,
    Count(CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 12 THEN ReviewType END) AS Dec,
count(ReviewType) AS Result
FROM SQL1.dbo.qryPeakReviews 
GROUP BY ReviewType 

Output:

ReviewType  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec Result
    1   0   17  29  11  10  5   0   0   13  4   6   1   96
    2   0   2   20  5   4   3   0   3   6   5   0   0   48
    3   0   1   15  12  6   3   0   2   6   2   2   0   49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier with a normalised data set:

```
WITH Counts AS(
    SELECT ReviewType,
           MONTH(dateCompleted) AS MonthNo,
           DATENAME(MONTH,dateCompleted) AS MonthName,
           COUNT(1) AS Total
    FROM dbo.qryPeakReviews
    GROUP BY ReviewType,
             MONTH(dateCompleted))
SELECT ReviewType,
       MonthName,
       SUM(Total) OVER (ORDER BY MonthNo ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningTotal
FROM Counts
ORDER BY MonthNo;
```

If you *must* have an unnormalised dataset, you just need to alter your cross tab a little:

```
SELECT ReviewType,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 1 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jan,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 2 THEN ReviewType END) AS Feb,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 3 THEN ReviewType END) AS Mar,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 4 THEN ReviewType END) AS Apr,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 5 THEN ReviewType END) AS May,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 6 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jun,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 7 THEN ReviewType END) AS Jul,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 8 THEN ReviewType END) AS Aug,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 9 THEN ReviewType END) AS Sep,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 10 THEN ReviewType END) AS Oct,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 11 THEN ReviewType END) AS Nov,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dateCompleted) <= 12 THEN ReviewType END) AS Dec,
       COUNT(ReviewType) AS Result
FROM dbo.qryPeakReviews 
GROUP BY ReviewType;
```

Comment: Thank you Larnu! I need a unnormalised dataset. The second one works perfect. Now, I have a different questions. How do I make it where July is the first Month. We use Fiscal Years July - June  instead of calendar years.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you need cumulative sum you can achieve it like :

```
SELECT t1.ReviewType,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 1 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Jan,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 2 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Feb,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 3 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Mar,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 4 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Apr,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 5 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS May,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 6 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Jun,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 7 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Jul,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 8 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Aug,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 9 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Sep,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 10 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Oct,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 11 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Nov,
     (CASE MONTH(dateCompleted) WHEN 12 THEN SUM(count(t2.ReviewType)) END) AS Dec,

FROM SQL1.dbo.qryPeakReviews t1
INNER JOIN SQL1.dbo.qryPeakReviews t2 ON t1.ReviewType >= t2.ReviewType
GROUP BY t1.ReviewType, count(t1.ReviewType)
ORDER BY MONTH(dateCompleted)
```

---

the actual idea is :

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.num, SUM(t2.num) as c_sum
FROM @t t1
INNER JOIN @t t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.num
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Output

```
| id | num      |c_sum|
-----------------------
|  1 |        5 |  5 |
|  2 |        7 |  12 |
|  3 |        3 |  15 |
|  4 |       15 |  30 |
|  5 |       20 |  50 |
```